# How to mock i18next?

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest, i18next

How do I mock this part of my code without shallow or mount?

```
import i18n from "i18next";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

...

i18n.use(initReactI18next).init({
    debug: false,
    fallbackNS: "defaultNS",
    defaultNS: site || "defaultNS",
    ns: ns,
    resources: resources,
    lng: language.toLowerCase(),
    fallbackLng: "en_us",
    keySeparator: false,
    whitelist: ["en_us", "en_ca", "fr_ca"],
        interpolation: {
            format: function (value) {
                 return value;
            },
        }
    });
```

I've tried this but it doesn't work

```
jest.mock("i18next", () => ({
    use: jest.fn(),
    init: jest.fn(),
    t: jest.fn(),
}));
```

So, I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: i18next_1.default.use is not a function